# How to reverse the operation of separate_rows in R by tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

The question is how to reverse operation of separate_rows, as shown in [Reverse summary to expand comma separated strings in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473183/reverse-summary-to-expand-comma-separated-strings-in-dataframe)

I just adopted the example but aims to realize the opposite purpose:
the original data is

```
df <- tibble(group=c("cat","cat","cat","dog","dog","dog","horse","horse","horse"),
             value=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
             list=c("siamese", "burmese", "balinese", "corgi", "sheltie", "collie", "arabian", "friesian", "andalusian"))



  group value       list
1   cat     1    siamese
2   cat     1    burmese
3   cat     1   balinese
4   dog     2      corgi
5   dog     2    sheltie
6   dog     2     collie
7 horse     3    arabian
8 horse     3   friesian
9 horse     3 andalusian
```

what I want to do is:

```
  group value                        list
1   cat     1    siamese,burmese,balinese
2   dog     2        corgi,sheltie,collie
3 horse     3 arabian,friesian,andalusian
```

Comment: `aggregate(list~ group + value, df, toString)`

Comment: Great, thank you, it really works. Are there any tidyverse alternatives?